# How to turn a dart function name into a string?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, tostring

for testing purposes, I want to be able to dynamically turn a function name like `getUserLocationByUserID(String userID){}` into a string `'getUserLocationByUserID'` so I can use it elseWhere

So When you have a list of functions and you wanna iterate in them I wish to be able to do something like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void function1() {}
void function2() {}
void function3() {}

List<Function> functionsList = [function1, function2, function3];

String magicalFunctionThatGetsAStringOutOfAFunctionName(Function function) {
  String functionNameAsAString = ''; // magical code here  <----------------------------------------------
  return functionNameAsAString;
}

class FunctionTester extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: functionsList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => GestureDetector(
          onTap: functionsList[index],
          child: Container(
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            child: Text(
              magicalFunctionThatGetsAStringOutOfAFunctionName(functionsList[index]),
              maxLines: 1,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 10,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
  String magicalFunctionThatGetsAStringOutOfAFunctionName(Function function) {
    String functionNameAsAString = function.toString();
    int s = functionNameAsAString.indexOf('\'');
    int e = functionNameAsAString.lastIndexOf('\'');

    return functionNameAsAString.substring(s + 1, e);
  }
```

This solution might be a bit hacky but quite cheap compare to other options.

Note: This can be simplified, I wrote it this way to be easy to read :)

Answer (score 3):

**As a one-liner function:**

```dart
String functionToString(Function fn) => fn.toString().split('\'')[1].trim();

void main() {
  print(functionToString(functionToString));
}
```

Console results:

```
functionToString
```

**As a `get` extension on `Function`:**

```dart
void main() {
  print(main.asString);
}

extension on Function {
  String get asString => this.toString().split('\'')[1].trim();
}
```

Console:

```
main
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible in Dart using [mirrors](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html), however mirrors are not available in Flutter or Web (and could be discontinued - see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44489).

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

void function1() {}
void function2() {}
void function3() {}

List<Function> functionsList = [function1, function2, function3];

void main() {
  for (final func in functionsList) {
    ClosureMirror mirror = reflect(func);
    final name = MirrorSystem.getName(mirror.function.simpleName);
    print(name);
  }
}
```

An alternative could be to use a map to store the function names with the function references, like:

```
void function1() {}
void function2() {}
void function3() {}

final functions = {
  'function1': function1,
  'function2': function2,
  'function3': function3,
};

void main() {
  for (final functionName in functions.keys) {
    final function = functions[functionName];
    print(functionName);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since mirrors aren't available in Flutter, I suggest you take a look at code gen libraries, where you can programmatically generate code based on your code.